# Is my rice cactus healthy?

Tags: plant-health, succulents, cactus, repotting

I've had this rice cactus for a few years but lately one of its main "branches" has been falling over.  I'm not sure if this is normal for this plant to do or not. And I just want to know if its healthy or not?

I repotted it yesterday but I couldn't see the colour of the roots because they had soil all over them and I didn't want to accidentally snap the roots but I know they weren't completely black

[image: plant after repotting]

Comment: Your cactus looks very healthy, though your new pot is huge and will therefore dry out too slowly. Can you switch it to a 3" pot? I can also see dividing into 3 plants in 3 pots.

Comment: Update: ive transfered it into a smaller plastic pot with better drainage (but bigger then its previous pot) turns out the roots covered in soil where dead but when i got closer to the center of the plant its roots where beige/white but very rootbound so i untangled the roots